# Effects of java super class call

Tags: java, oop, inheritance

I'm new to Java and I'm having problems with some OOP, mostly inheritance, concepts.

Consider these two classes:

```
public class Foo() {
    protected String rawData;
    public String getSomething(String rawData) {
        // ...
        this.rawData = rawData;
        prepareData();
        return rawData;
    }

    protected void prepareData() {
        // do something with class rawData
    }
}

public class Bar() extends Foo {
    @Override
    public String getSomething(String rawData) {
        // ...
        return super.rawData;
    }

    @Override
    protected void prepareData() {
        // do something with class rawData too
    }
}
```

Calling `Bar` class `getSomething()` method will lead me to a call of `Foo` class `prepareData()`?

Comment: No, why would it?

Answer (score 1):

Only if your override calls the base method.

Other than base class constructors, Java does not silently call methods for you.

Answer (score 0):

Java always goes deeper even without `@Override`.
If you don't override the base method it will run it.

If you are in Bar and you want to run Foo method, you can use `super.prepareData()` in Bar - It will be use when you want to run the super method and add something to it.